# Why does print statement change gzread behavior?

Tags: c, fortran, gzip, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm trying to read a gzip file in Fortran using the C functions gzopen, gzread, and gzclose from the [zlib library](http://www.zlib.net/).  My subroutine works properly when it contains a print statement, but gives a `Z_STREAM_ERROR (-2)` without it.  What is causing this to happen, and how can I fix it?

```
module gzmodule
    use :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    private
    public fastunzip

    interface
        type(c_ptr) function gzopen(filename,mode) bind(c)
            use :: iso_c_binding
            character(kind=c_char), dimension(*) :: filename
            character(kind=c_char), dimension(*) :: mode
        end function gzopen
    end interface

    interface
        integer(c_int) function gzread(gzfile,buffer,length) bind(c)
            use :: iso_c_binding
            type(c_ptr), value :: gzfile
            character(len=1,kind=c_char) :: buffer(*)
            integer(c_int) :: length
        end function gzread
    end interface

    interface
        integer(c_int) function gzclose(gzfile) bind(c)
            use :: iso_c_binding
            type(c_ptr), value :: gzfile
        end function
    end interface

    contains

        subroutine fastunzip(filename, isize,abuf,ierr)
            use :: iso_c_binding
            character(len=*,kind=c_char), intent(in) :: filename
            integer(c_int), intent(out) :: isize
            character(len=1,kind=c_char), intent(inout) :: abuf(:,:,:,:)
            integer(4), intent(out) :: ierr
            type(c_ptr) :: gzfile
            integer(c_int) :: iclose
            logical :: c_associated
            ierr = 1  !! indicates that an error has occured
            isize = 0
            gzfile = gzopen(trim(filename)//c_null_char,"rb")
            if (.not.c_associated(gzfile)) return
            isize = gzread(gzfile,abuf,size(abuf))
            print*,isize  !! why do I need this for it to work?
            if (isize.ne.size(abuf)) return
            iclose = gzclose(gzfile)
            if (iclose.ne.0) return
            ierr = 0  !! success
        end subroutine fastunzip

end module gzmodule

program main
    use gzmodule        
    implicit none

    character(100) :: filename = './f10_19950120v7.gz'
    integer(4) :: isize
    integer(4) :: ierr
    logical(4) :: exists

    integer(4), parameter :: nlon = 1440
    integer(4), parameter :: nlat = 720
    integer(4), parameter :: nvar = 5
    integer(4), parameter :: nasc = 2
    character(1) :: abuf(nlon,nlat,nvar,nasc)

    inquire(file=filename,exist=exists)
    if (.not.exists) stop 'file not found'

    call fastunzip(filename, isize,abuf,ierr)
    print*,'return value of isize ',isize
    if (ierr.ne.0) stop 'error in fastunzip'

    print*,'done'    
end program main
```

I'm on CentOS and compiling with:

```
gfortran -o example_usage.exe example_usage.f90 /lib64/libz.so.1
```

and the data file is available at [this site](ftp://ftp.remss.com/ssmi/f10/bmaps_v07/y1995/m01/f10_19950120v7.gz).

Comment: What exactly is returning -2?  `gzread()` can only return a non-negative number of bytes read, or -1 for an error.

Comment: francescalus: yes, indeed!  Mark: I was getting isize=-2 from "isize = gzread(gzfile,abuf,size(abuf))"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In subroutine `fastunzip` you declare `logical :: c_associated`.  However, you get this function by use association (of `iso_c_binding`), so you should remove that line.

My installed gfortran (4.8) marks that as an error, so I guess you have an older version?  But once I remove that line your code appears to work even without the `print`, so perhaps that is worth trying for you.

On a style note, I'd recommend `use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding`, perhaps even with `only` (which would also flag to you that the `c_associated` is through use association).

Comment: francescalus: the "logical" declaration was exactly the problem, and thank you for the "only" recommendation ... yikes, I was using gfortran 4.4